# Negative Values in an Array in Assembly Language

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

In my x86 assembly language class we were given this problem:

Prompt the user to input an array of signed byte values .Draft a program that scans the array testing each index for a negative value. When a negative value is found, the program should print “found” and the value.  If no negative value is found the program should print “not found.”
        Use:

```
.data
        myArray1 SBYTE -12,4,1,23,-21,45,12,-2
```

I have no problem scanning through the array, but I have absolutely no idea how to pick out a negative value form that array. Can anyone explain how to go about finding a negative value in an array?

Comment: Which part is causing you problems? Do you know there is a sign flag and matching conditional branch? Can you iterate the array? Show your code. See also [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to detect negative numbers. For beginners, probably the most intuitive is to compare with zero and branch if less. I trust you know how to use `CMP` and `JL` to achieve this.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of how to use those instructions, but I'm not sure what you mean by "branch"

Comment: `JL` is a conditional branch. Do you know how to use conditional branches (jumps)?

Comment: I have a very very basic understanding of conditional jumps.

Comment: That should be all you need. Do you have a problem using `CMP` and `JL` to test for negative as I outlined in the answer or not? You claim you have no problem iterating the array and that already involves using a conditional jump.